# What is the difference between string and character in R?

Tags: string, r

I'm not pretty familiar with R, but anyhow I'm writing a R wrapper for a c library. I come across this problem. How do I decide if the input argument is a string? In details,should I write like this:

```
dyn.load("hello.so")
do_process <- function(str) {
        if(!is.character(str))
            stop("not a character or string");
    result <- .Call("hello", as.character(str))
    return result
}
```

or this:

```
dyn.load("hello.so")
do_process <- function(str) {
        if(!is.string(str))
            stop("not a character or string");
    result <- .Call("hello", as.string(str))
    return result
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: In base `R` there is no function `is.string` nor is there a data type `string`.  They are `as.character` and `character`.  Also, avoid using important base functions as variable names.  Specifically `str` is used to view the structure of an object.

Comment: @Justin I do not know but I 've read `is.string` usage here: http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/xtable/html/string.html, and thanks for the advice on `str` usage.

Comment: @Justin My fault. Thank you for pointing out the mistake.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`is.string` is a function from the `xtable` package.  In the details section of the help page it explicitly says "These functions are private functions used by print.xtable. They are not intended to be used elsewhere."

As such, I would avoid using those functions.

In `R` there is no `string` data type.  Instead it is called `character` and you can use `is.character` to do the check you're describing.

Also, as I mentioned in my comment, avoid using important base functions as variable names. Specifically `str` is used to view the structure of an object.

Answer (score 10):

In R, there's no fundamental distinction between a string and a character. A "string" is just a character variable that contains one or more characters.

One thing you *should* be aware of, however, is the distinction between a *scalar* character variable, and a *vector*. A character vector is a set of strings stored as a single object. Most R functions that work on character input are vectorised, ie they will return the appropriate value for each element in such a vector.

For example:

```
# a string containing one character
x <- "a"
nchar(x)
# 1

# a string containing multiple characters
x <- "foo"
nchar(x)
# 3

# a character vector: two strings, each containing three characters
x <- c("foo", "bar")

# length() returns the no. of elements in a vector, NOT the length of each string
length(x)
# 2

# nchar() returns the length of each string in a vector
nchar(x)
# 3 3
```

Comment: Oops, I think I need to check my binding code right now! Is the R_allocVector function return a scalar character variable or a vector?