# How to allocate a string with c api of R?

Tags: string, r

I've asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513200/what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-character-in-r/), and that led me to an another question.

> In R, there's no fundamental distinction between a string and a
>   character. A "string" is just a character variable that contains one
>   or more characters.

and

> There is a distinction between a scalar character variable, and a
>   vector. A character vector is a set of strings stored as a single
>   object.

So I wonder how to allocate a string with c api of R? For example, what do I get from:

```
result = Rf_allocVector(STRSXP, dst_size);
```

is it(the `result`) a `scalar character variable` or a `vector`? or could I use other API for allocating string?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're looking for another API the `Rcpp` library provides a nice wrapper for C++ code, handling all that allocation for you in an intuitive way.

Comment: See Section 5.9 of "Writing R Extensions".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that as a motivating example in our introductory vignette in the [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) package (and this is also published as a [paper JSS in 2011](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i08)):

In the C API you must do allocate a vector of `STRSXP`:

```
SEXP ab;
PROTECT(ab = allocVector(STRSXP, 2));
SET_STRING_ELT( ab, 0, mkChar("foo") );
SET_STRING_ELT( ab, 1, mkChar("bar") );
UNPROTECT(1);
```

which imposes on the programmer knowledge of `PROTECT`, `UNPROTECT`,
`SEXP`, `allocVector`, `SET_STRING_ELT`, and `mkChar`.

Whereas with Rcpp and
using the `Rcpp::CharacterVector` class, we can express the same code more concisely:

```
Rcpp::CharacterVector ab(2);
ab[0] = "foo";
ab[1] = "bar";
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I am using the C API and quite unclear about all those concepts. Your answer gives me a clue.