# R: Converting a column of IDs toString is grouping them into comma separated values instead of turning the field type to string

Tags: r

I have data (1000 obs. of 9 variables) that has a field called Employee containing 5 number values for each record. When I run the below code to convert the chr type to string, the ID field groups all of my IDs in the dataset into comma separated values and puts them in each row, with the data still having 1000 obs. and 9 variables.  I want to group my data by Employee, which is why I am converting it toString.

`Data$Employee <- toString(Data$Employee)`

[Column before converting toString, when data type is character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f86M0.png)
[Column after converting toString with above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo3HF.png)

Comment: Maybe you want `as.character`

Answer (score 1):

The wording of your question is a little confusing, but I think you are trying to convert a numeric vector into a character vector and are running into trouble. If that is correct, I have an answer. Otherwise, feel free to stop reading here!

The function `toString()` in R creates a single character vector separated by comma values. For example:

```
toString(c(1, 2, 3))
```

gives "1, 2, 3".

If however, you want to turn a numeric vector into a character vector in R, you want to use the function `as.character()`.

All that to say,

```
Data$ID <- as.character(Data$ID)
```

should give you what you're looking for!

Comment: I think you may be a little confused about string vs. character in R. In R there is no object class 'string'. Anything you would thing of as a string is a ```character``` in R. Check this question out for more info. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513200/what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-character-in-r.

Comment: Hi, I added two pictures to show you my data before and after. Apologies for the confusing wording.

I want to convert a column to string from character.

Comment: @Veronica There is no class called 'string' in R. If your vector is a 'character' vector then it is already where you want it to be!

Comment: You're right- still learning and I had that concept wrong. Thank you!

Comment: @Veronica You're welcome! If the answer is satisfactory, accept it using the check symbol to let other users know that the question is answered!